# Beamer: Table of contentes of current section and subsections

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, sectioning

I am using `\tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]` to show only the sections on the first slide and the `\AtBeginSection` command to display the table of contents at the beginning of each section of my presentation, but it show all of the ToC again.
How do I show only the current section **AND** its subsections?

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

```
\tableofcontents[hideothersubsections]
```

Comment: This is actually a good idea!
It is not exactly what I was looking for, since the other section still show up. But using `\tableofcontents[currentsection,hideothersubsections]` is going to be useful for my presentation. Thank you @samcarter!