# Display only outline for current section in beamer

Tags: beamer

This is a duplicate of this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/345547/beamer-table-of-contentes-of-current-section-and-subsections), but it was not answered fully in my opinion. I am also trying to only show the current section and its subsections. So I would like something similar to `hideothersubsections` just with `hideothersections`. Is that possible?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
%\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}


\usetheme{Antibes}

\title{The Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\author[F. Author]{F.author\inst{1}\and S. Autor\inst{2}}
\institute[University of Somewhere and Elsewhere] {
    \inst{1}
        UofS
    \and
    \inst{2}%
        UofE
}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Table of Contents}  
    \tableofcontents[  
    sectionstyle=show, 
    hideallsubsections
    ] 
\end{frame}
\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}
Frame 
\end{frame}
\subsection{subsection1}
\begin{frame}
Frame 
\end{frame}

\AtBeginSection[]
  {
     \begin{frame}<beamer>
     \frametitle{Outline}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection
                        , hideothersubsections
                        ] 
     \end{frame}
  }
\section[Section2]{Section 2}
\subsection{Model Overview}
\begin{frame}
Frame 
\end{frame}
\subsection{Characteristics of Model}
\begin{frame}
Frame 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Basically I would like to remove the shaded heading of Section 1 in the Outline at the beginning of section 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display only the current section, you can use `\tableofcontents[sections=\value{section}]`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
%\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}


\usetheme{Antibes}

\title{The Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\author[F. Author]{F.author\inst{1}\and S. Autor\inst{2}}
\institute[University of Somewhere and Elsewhere] {
    \inst{1}
        UofS
    \and
    \inst{2}%
        UofE
}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Table of Contents}  
    \tableofcontents[  
    sectionstyle=show, 
    hideallsubsections
    ] 
\end{frame}
\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}
Frame 
\end{frame}
\subsection{subsection1}
\begin{frame}
Frame 
\end{frame}

\AtBeginSection[]
  {
     \begin{frame}<beamer>
     \frametitle{Outline}
            \tableofcontents[sections=\value{section}]
     \end{frame}
  }

\section[Section2]{Section 2}
\subsection{Model Overview}
\begin{frame}
Frame 
\end{frame}
\subsection{Characteristics of Model}
\begin{frame}
Frame 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```